# trap of primary key error

Tags: c#, error-handling, primary-key

i wants to trap sql-2000 primary key error into c# and develop my own error like
"this is duplicate Invoice Number"

kindly reply how to do this in c# application.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is not considered good design. You should check for duplicate keys *before* inserting, and rely on DB constraints as a "safety net" only.

But if you feel like doing this, you need to catch the exception SQLException. Then you need to use SQLException's attribute (in particular ErrorCode and Number) to check to see if it is a PK violation.

But generally checking the exact reason of an SQLException is tricky and depends on the DBMS used, so it's not a nice and robust approach. That's one of the reasons why it's not recommended (see above).

Answer (score -1):

Rather than handling it as an exception, if you expect it to happen, you should check to see if a particular ID exists prior to inserting it.

Comment: -1 That's even worse than catching the exception, because it causes a race condition (what if some other client uses the ID between the time you check and the time you use it).

Comment: It depends on how it is done - if it is handled in a stored procedure in a transactional fashion, then this should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that could be made to work, but it's rather non-trivial, and probably significantly reduces performance (the whole table must be locked), so why bother? Anyway, feel free to add all this to your answer (then I'd probably remove the downvote).